# If $\tau$ is a $\mu$-preserving bijection with measurable inverse, then $\mu(\tau(B))=\mu(B)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space and $\tau:E\to E$ be $(\mathcal E,\mathcal E)$-measurable with $$\mu(\tau^{-1}(B))=\mu(B)\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal E\tag1.$$

Assume that $\tau$ is bijective and $\tau^{-1}$ is $(\mathcal E,\mathcal E)$-measurable as well. How can we conclude that $\mu(\tau(B))=\mu(B)$ for all $B\in\mathcal E$? In particular, that $\tau(B)\in\mathcal E$ for all $\in\mathcal E$.

This should be almost trivial, but I'm not sure how we even can conclude the measurability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measurability of $\tau^{-1}$ means $\tau (B)=(\tau^{-1})^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for every measurable set $B$.

We get $\mu ( \tau (B))=\mu (B)$ by replacing $C$ by $\tau (B)$ in  in $\mu ( \tau^{-1} (C))=C$

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that $\tau(B)=(\tau^{-1})^{-1}(B)$. It is sufficient that $\tau$ is injective for the claim in the question to hold, if I'm not missing something, right?

Comment: If $\tau$ is not surjective then we have to assume that $\tau (E)$ is   a Borel set and the inverse map from $\tau (B)$ to $E$ is measurable. @0xbadf00d

Comment: I think we don't need to assume that $\tau(E)$ is measurable. We only need that $\tau^{-1}$ is measurable from $(\tau(E),\left.\mathcal E\right|_{\tau(E)})$ to $(E,\mathcal E)$, or am I missing something?

Comment: @0xbadf00d We are given that $\mu ( \tau^{-1} (C))=C$ for $C \in \mathcal E$. If we want to take $C=\tau (B)$ we have to assume that $\tau (B) \in \mathcal E$, right?

Comment: Yes, right. I guess we need to assume $\tau(B)\in\mathcal E$, sine then $\left.\mathcal E\right|_{\tau(E)}=\{B\in\mathcal E:B\subseteq\tau(E)\}$.